# Number of columns in an HTML table based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-resolution

I have a simple table, that looks different in same resolution screens.[image: image comparison]

My goal would be to detect if there's more screen space available and render more columns accordingly. But with Javascript and media queries I can only detect the size of the window in pixels and that is the same in this case.

The table has min-width and max-width defined I have no idea why it looks smaller on bigger screens. The Windows taskbar has identical height in both screenshot. Is there some scaling setting I am missing here?

Comment: Why not test [resolution](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution)?

Comment: Fix your table width in a percentage instead of pixels.

Comment: same things..i agreed it.Fix table with everything in percentage.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai that could work, but what if the current situation is good for me, but I want to have more columns rendered in the first image?

Comment: try adding this to your head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` + setting everything in %